# WPF: Binding DependencyProperty in DataTemplate. PropertyChangedCallback not fired

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Today I have really hard situation. I can't figure because of lack of experience with WPF. I develop small framework for GUI generation(WinForms\WPF\HTML) from class. For this I need to create elements dynamically.

I have custom UserControl with DependencyProperty

```
public partial class ObjectPicker : UserControl
    {
        private ViewModel _vm;
        public ObjectPicker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public object ObjectValue
        {
            get { return GetValue(ObjectValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ObjectValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty ObjectValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "ObjectValue",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(ObjectPicker),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    new PropertyMetadata(new object(), OnObjectChangeNotify, CoerceValueCallback), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

        private static void OnObjectChangeNotify(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sender = d as ObjectPicker;
            sender.OnObjectValueChange(d, e);
        }

        public void OnObjectValueChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ObjectValue = e.NewValue;
        }
    }
```

I have CustomBoundColumn where I override GenerateElement method (where BindingObject - wrapper with 2 properties Value and PropName). Then I bind object like this, then it not working.

```
        var content = new ContentControl();
        content.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)cell.FindResource(TemplateName);
        var propName = ((Binding)Binding).Path.Path;
        BindingObject bo = new BindingObject(propName, dataItem);
        content.SetValue(ContentControl.ContentProperty, bo);
        return content;
```

Data template(for example I put two another templates which work perfect):

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxDataTemplate">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DatePickerDataTemplate">
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ObjectPickerDataTemplate">
        <local:ObjectPicker ObjectValue="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

When I binding programmatically like this:

```
objectPicker.SetBinding(ObjectPicker.ObjectValueProperty, binding);
```

When it works.

I don't know what additional information need for resolve this question. If you need more just leave the comment and I add it.

UPDATE1: add BindingObject class

```
public class BindingObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object _value;
    private PropertyDescriptor _pd;
    private MethodInfo _method;

    public BindingObject(string propName, object value)
    {
        _method = value.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "OnPropertyChanged");
        if (!(value is INotifyPropertyChanged) || _method == null) throw new Exception("Invalid value");
        _value = value;
        _pd = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(_value.GetType())[propName];

        (_value as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
            OnPropertyChanged(_pd.Name);
        };
    }

    public string PropName
    {
        get { return _pd.Name; }
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _pd.GetValue(_value);
        }
        set
        {
            _pd.SetValue(_value, value);

        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged()
    {
        _method.Invoke(_value, new[] { nameof(Value) });
        _method.Invoke(_value, new[] { _pd.Name });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

UPDATE2: Implementation example of dataItem

```
public class DataItem
{
      public virtual string Value1 { get; set; } // This type of property work fine and binding 
      public virtual int Value2 { get; set; } // This type of property work fine and binding 
      public virtual DateTime Value3 { get; set; } // This type of property work fine and binding 
      public virtual ExampleComplexObject Object { get; set; } // This type not working

}

public class ExampleComplexObject
{
      public virtual int Value1 { get; set; }
      public virtual string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

At runtime then need to create object type pass to the factory where create proxy object from passed type with INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your exact issue here but you could try to set the Content property of the ContentControl to the data object:

```
var content = new ContentControl();
content.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)cell.FindResource(TemplateName);
content.SetValue(ContentControl.ContentProperty, dataItem);
return content;
```

Then you should be able to bind to the Value property in the DataTemplate(s) using `{Binding Value}`.

Comment: I clarify this moment BindingObject this is a object wrapper, which realise INotifyPropertyChange interface. BindingObject type have property Value, which I need binding. I can add this class to the start post for more understanding. PS. dataItem here is the row of main object. ObjectPickerDataTemplate - Column with complex type property of the main object.

Comment: How is the dataItem class defined and how is the ObjectPicker UserControl related to this issue? You are creating a ContentControl in the GenerateElement method, aren't you?

Comment: dataItem is a variable from GenerateElement method parameters (protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem) dataItem here is a object of the SourceItems). Then property of dataItem is a complex type, then I put ObjectPicker component in a cell ((DataTemplate)cell.FindResource(TemplateName);)

Comment: I know where the "dataItem" argument comes from but how is the source object defined? And how does the XAML markup of the ObjectPicker control look like? How do you set the value of the source property from the ObjectPicker control?

Comment: Look main post. I updated it. I haven't any XAML code on the component I think first step is make binding to the custom property. Is this mistake?